# Curl to GuzzleHttp request

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I have been given the following curl request:

`curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Api-Key:someapikey" -X -d {"address":"30598 West Street","city":"Oakdale"}' PUT "https://somedomain/api/members/1234567"`

I am trying to replicate this with [GuzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) like so:

```
$headers = [
    'Api-Key'      => $this->apiKey,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];
$client = new Client([
    'headers' => $headers,
]);
$res = $client->put("{$this->baseUrl}/members/{$fields['vip_id']}", [
    'form_params' => $fields,
]);
```

I keep on getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type response. From the curl I was given I think I have all my bases covered. However, when I debug it shows that my Content Type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. According to the documentation, the header is set to this only if the Content-Type header isn't already set and form_params is included. As I am already setting this header, it shouldn't be switching right? Please help!

Comment: what do you have in $fields?

Comment: an array like so `[ 'field1' => 'value1' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your headers are being overridden is because the `form_params` option to the request is specifically for sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

You can omit the `Content-Type` header from your options completely and instead use the `json` key in the request to send JSON data.

```
$headers = [
    'Api-Key'      => $this->apiKey,
];
$client = new Client([
    'headers' => $headers,
]);
$res = $client->put("{$this->baseUrl}/members/{$fields['vip_id']}", [
    'json' => $fields, // causes Guzzle to set content type to application/json
                       // and json_encode your $fields
]);
```

Comment: According to the documentation AND the code, form_params should only change the Content-Type if its not already set. I would think that setting it in the constructor would count but for some reason it doesn't. Not sure why that is. I looked at the code where it checks the conditional and the header wasn't set at that point even if i set it in the constructor. Who knows. This DOES work though. So its the answer.

Comment: Yeah the docs do say that but it may be outdated or incorrect.  The [code](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/310b854261b0b0b10abb4cc096e3171fd4c21abb/src/Client.php#L293) appears to set the content-type to urlencoded when form_params is set and then creates the request based on that.  It looks like it overrides the existing content-type header.  The sendAsync function in Client calls prepareDefaults (sets your default Content-Type, then calls transfer which calls applyOptions which sets the content type based on the form_params or json options.  (shrug)